# my xterm terminal just having basic black UI it is lacking logic , pls look into it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, terminal, xtermjs

I have tried many things but still it is not able to build up the logic of a terminal. I have used the xterm-for-react package as well but it was still giving the same black UI only

```
const Xterm = () => {
  const termRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const initTerminal = () => {
      const terminal = new Terminal();
      const fitAddon = new FitAddon();
      terminal.loadAddon(fitAddon);
      terminal.open(termRef.current);
      fitAddon.fit();

      terminal.onKey((e) => {
        const printable = !e.domEvent.altKey && !e.domEvent.altGraphKey && !e.domEvent.ctrlKey && !e.domEvent.metaKey;

        if (e.domEvent.key === 13) {
          terminal.write('\r\n');
        } else if (e.domEvent.key=== 8) {
          // Do something when backspace is pressed
        } else if (printable) {
          terminal.write(e.key);
        }
      });
    };

    initTerminal();
  }, []);

  return <div ref={termRef}></div>;
};

export default Xterm;
```

Comment: Your `onKey` looks right to me to get very basic REPL output from xtermjs. My guess is, that your lifecycling with `useEffect` is wrong. Wouldnt this recreate the terminal every time, ergo you only get an empty initial screen?

Answer (score 0):

xtermjs is only a visualization tool it doesn't have a built-in terminal logic. Check this in xtermjs official [github](https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js#what-xtermjs-is-not) page:

> Xterm.js is not a terminal application that you can download and use on your computer.
> Xterm.js is not bash. Xterm.js can be connected to processes like bash and let you interact with them (provide input, receive output).

If you want to run processes like bash, vim etc. you should run a terminal process in the background and connect it with your js code. You can check [this github project](https://github.com/robert-harbison/xterm-for-react) if you want to use it with React.

Comment: Your answer is a bit misleading - xtermjs is a terminal emulator and thus has built-in terminal logic. But to work properly, it has to be connected to a PTY (or the PTY functionality has to be shimmed by other means). And yes - it is not a terminal application and also not a shell, because those run typcially IN the terminal, while xtermjs IS the terminal (emulator).